# BroadcastReceiver for when sent SMS messages are deleted?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider

Is there a broadcast event for when the user deletes everything inside the phone's sent SMS folder? I need to be able to trigger an action when the user clears her sent box.

If not the entire sent box, at least the messages individually--that is, do something when this particular sent message has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my approach to this problem in my app and no longer need a listener for when SMS messages are deleted, but it might help to:

1. Create a `ContentObserver` that listens to the `Uri` `content:\\sms`.
2. Do something from the `ContentObserver` when `onChange()` is executed. For example, you might want to traverse all the messages in the inbox (via `Cursor`) and check which messages are missing. That of course requires you to have an archive of messages that were present in a previous check.